# How to turn HTML elements into array in specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays

The table itself

```
 <body>
 <canvas width = 800px height = 400px id="myChart"></canvas>
 <table id="my-table" >

  <tr id="default-row">
    <td class = "xcell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "xcell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "xcell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "xcell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td class = "ycell" contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="addColumn" class="add">
  <div id="addColumnChild"><b>+</b></div>
</div>
<div id="addRow" class="add">
  <div id="addRowChild"><b>+</b></div>
</div>
<button onclick = "chartIt()"></button>
```

This function gets values from the table

```
 
    async function getTableData(){
    const xs = [] //x axis values
    const ys = [] //y axis values
    const x = document.querySelectorAll(".xcell").forEach((item, i) => {
        if(Number.isNaN(parseFloat(item.textContent))){ //checks if passed value is NaN
        xs.push(0)
    }
    else{xs.push(parseFloat(item.textContent))} //checks if NaN is passed into the array and pushes values from table into xs array if so
      });
    const y = document.querySelectorAll(".ycell").forEach((item, i) => {
        ys.push(parseFloat(item.textContent)) //pushes values from table into ys array
      });;
      console.log(xs, ys);
    return {xs, ys}}
```

Function that creates a chart

```
async function chartIt(){
const data = await getTableData()
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let chartStatus = Chart.getChart("myChart")
if (chartStatus != undefined){
 chartStatus.destroy()
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: data.xs,
    datasets: [{
        label: '',
        data: data.ys,
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            ticks: {
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    return value + "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
})
}
```

Here is my code. It takes values from xs and ys arrays entered by user into a table and graphs it into a chart, but the thing is that I want it to take all y axis values for every x axis one. The thing is that table is changed dynamically by user so all of the solutions i've tried just can't be applied to my code.

So i want my second(i guess) function to get all y axis values from the whole row and graph it

Comment: how do you want to keep the y axis values? as a array o arrays?
[x] [y, y, y]

Comment: As two arrays, if you please